# markov chain on state {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7}

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

[markov chain on state {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 , 7}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViCzC.png)

[image]

what are the probabilities of states  1 ,  2 , and  4  in the stationary distribution of the Markov chain  s  shown in the image. The label to the left of an arrow gives the corresponding transition probability.

Comment: Do you know how to form the probability transition matrix, and find the eigenvector of the dominant eigenvalue?

Comment: @Joe, no, I am just needing that information for a programming project.

Comment: Form a 7x7 matrix $A$, such that each entry $a_{ij}$ is the value on the arc going from node $i$ to node $j$. Check that you didn’t make a mistake by checking that each row sums to one. A stationary distribution is a solution to the equation $x = xA$, for the row vector $x$.

Comment: Since your probability transition matrix has only positive entries, by the Perron–Frobenius theorem, there is only one dominant eigenvalue. It will equal one. The only left eigenvector (or right eigenvector of $A^{\top}$) that sums to one is the stationary state.

Comment: @Joe can you help with this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672915/bernoulli-trails

Answer (score 1):

This is an discrete finite ergodic Markov Chain so there is a unique stationary distribution $\pi$ with $\sum \pi_i =1$.  Here are three approaches:

1. Looking at the symmetries and shape of your diagram

   - $\pi_2=\pi_3$ and $\pi_4=\pi_5=\pi_6=\pi_7$.
   - To keep the distribution stationary, you need $0.4 \pi_1=0.2 \pi_2$ so $\pi_2=2\pi_1$;
   - you also have $0.4 \pi_2=0.2 \pi_4$ so $\pi_4 = 2\pi_2 =4\pi_1$.
   - Since $\sum \pi_i =1$, you get $\pi_1=\frac{1}{1+2\times 2+4\times4}=\frac{1}{21}$ and thus $\pi_2=\frac2{21}$ and $\pi_4=\frac4{21}$, which are about $0.047619$, $0.095238$ and $0.190476$
2. The transition matrix is $P=\left(\begin{matrix}
     0.2 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
     0.2 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
     0.2 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\
     0.0 & 0.2 & 0.0 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
     0.0 & 0.2 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.8 & 0.0 & 0.0 \\
     0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.8 & 0.0 \\
     0.0 & 0.0 & 0.2 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.8 \end{matrix}\right)$

   - $P^n$ converges as $n$ increases, and the rows of the limit give you the staionary distribution.
   - For example, the top row of $P^{100}$ is `0.04761905 0.09523810 0.09523810 0.1904762 0.1904762 0.1904762 0.1904762` close to the exact result while the second row is `0.04761905 0.09746764 0.09300855 0.1958588 0.1958588 0.1850936 0.1850936` is a little further away and might need a higher value of $n$
3. Consider the left eigenvalues and left eigenvectors of $P$ (your computer system might prefer the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $P^T$)

   - The left eigenvalues are $1, \frac25(1+\sqrt2), \frac45,\frac45,-\frac25, \frac25, \frac25(1-\sqrt2)$.
   - My computer gives the left eigenvector associated with $1$ as $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{73}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{73}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{73}}, \frac{4}{\sqrt{73}}, \frac{4}{\sqrt{73}}, \frac{4}{\sqrt{73}}, \frac{4}{\sqrt{73}}\right)$ where the sum of squares is $1$
   - The values of that eigenvector do not sum to $1$ without squaring, but rescaling gives $\left(\frac{1}{21}, \frac{2}{21}, \frac{2}{21}, \frac{4}{21}, \frac{4}{21}, \frac{4}{21}, \frac{4}{21}\right)$ which does sum to $1$ and so is the stationary distribution

Comment: what application are you using to get the eigenvectors/eigenvalues?

Comment: @adhg I use R and its `eigen()` function but there are other languages which are more specifically designed to handle matrices, notably MATLAB and OCTAVE

Comment: @Henry for this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632893/markoc-chain-on-the-state-space-1-2-3-4-5-6

Comment: @user12609507 The same three methods suitably adapted will work there too

Comment: @adhg For stationary distributions, you only need to compute left eigenvectors of $1$, so you just need a way to compute the null space of $P^T-I$. That’s a much simpler task.

Comment: @amd ok thank you!

Comment: @Henry could you help with this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672915/bernoulli-trails

Comment: @Henry Hi can you help with this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692956/bernoulli-distributions